# Best way to display logs in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I am currently working on a GUI using qt designer. I am wondering how I should go about printing strings on the GUI that acts like a logger window. I am using pyqt5.

Comment: Bing users should go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469662/how-to-redirect-logger-output-into-pyqt-text-widget) :P

Answer (score 45):

Adapted from [Todd Vanyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2623625/todd-vanyo)'s example for PyQt5:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import logging

# Uncomment below for terminal log messages
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(parent)
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.widget.appendPlainText(msg)


class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        logTextBox = QTextEditLogger(self)
        # You can format what is printed to text box
        logTextBox.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(logTextBox)
        # You can control the logging level
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        self._button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self._button.setText('Test Me')

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        # Add the new logging box widget to the layout
        layout.addWidget(logTextBox.widget)
        layout.addWidget(self._button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Connect signal to slot
        self._button.clicked.connect(self.test)

    def test(self):
        logging.debug('damn, a bug')
        logging.info('something to remember')
        logging.warning('that\'s not right')
        logging.error('foobar')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
dlg = MyDialog()
dlg.show()
dlg.raise_()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### Threading issues

<sup>Note: as of late 2022, this is still the highest ranked answer. The OP doesn't seem to be active anymore, so I took the liberty of editing it because the lack of explanation of the implications of its usage is a common cause of closely related questions.</sup>

Be aware that the above code will only work for *single threaded* programs. If you are sure that your program doesn't use threading, then it's fine. Be aware, though: you have to be ***completely*** sure about that, also considering external modules. Qt included.

Don't underestimate this aspect: even some Qt classes that are thread safe are actually not single threaded; for instance, QFileSystemModel is a thread safe object, but it *does* use threading for file system crawling. If it faces a problem for any reason (ie. access permissions), it will output some debug messages from those threads, and you'll probably still get issues.

Possible results of underestimated threading issues while accessing UI elements include:

- unexpected behavior;
- drawing artifacts;
- lots of "unrelated" debug messages;
- possible fatal crash of the program;

So, as a rule of thumb, the above has to be considered as **unsafe** and should **not** be used, since it attempts to access the QPlainTextEdit widget even from external threads: widgets are not thread-safe, and can only be accessed from the main thread.
Since there is no immediate way to know if the logging source is in the same thread or not without pointlessly affecting performance, it's better to always use a thread safe solution in any case (see the other answers that consider this aspect).

Comment: how to use in in other case, I have *.ui with QMainWindow, QTabWidget with  tab (name tab_log) all defind in ui file. How to add QTextEditLogger to tab in QTabWidget???

Comment: This is not thread safe. `appendPlainText` should be connected to a signal instead of calling it.

Comment: I get the following error message: `AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'Handler'`

Comment: Gives me an error `Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType()` while logging via callbacks. The thread safe version worked quite well for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60528393/3598205

Comment: To anybody believing this answer is valid: ***DO NOT DO THIS*** unless you're **completely** sure that you're only using *one* thread. As already pointed out above, it is absolutely **NOT** thread safe: it will create drawing issues, will output multiple errors in the console and will also probably crash the program. This answer should not have so many votes, as it is dangerous to use without being aware of its consequences.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using the Python `logging` module to can easily create a custom logging handler that passes the log messages through to a `QPlainTextEdit` instance (as described by Christopher).

To do this you first subclass `logging.Handler`. In this `__init__` we create the `QPlainTextEdit` that will contain the logs. The key bit here is that the handle will be receiving messages via the `emit()` function. So we overload this function and pass the message text into the `QPlainTextEdit`.

```
import logging

class QPlainTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QPlainTextEditLogger, self).__init__()

        self.widget = QPlainTextEdit(parent)
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.widget.appendPlainText(msg)

    def write(self, m):
        pass
```

Create an object from this class, passing it the parent for the `QPlainTextEdit` (e.g. the main window, or a layout). You can then add this handler for the current logger.

```
# Set up logging to use your widget as a handler
log_handler = QPlainTextEditLogger(<parent widget>)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(log_handler)
```

Answer (score 20):

### Thread-safe version

```
class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler, QtCore.QObject):
    appendPlainText = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__()
    QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
    self.widget = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(parent)
    self.widget.setReadOnly(True)
    self.appendPlainText.connect(self.widget.appendPlainText)

def emit(self, record):
    msg = self.format(record)
    self.appendPlainText.emit(msg)
```

#### Usage

```
    logTextBox = QTextEditLogger(self)

    # log to text box
    logTextBox.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(funcName)s %(message)s'))
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(logTextBox)
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # log to file
    fh = logging.FileHandler('my-log.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(funcName)s %(message)s'))
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(fh)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although I am not sure why, with PySide2 (5.12.0) the double inheritance does not work for me. The error is that "emit() takes 2 positional argument but 3 are given". (this is the signal emit function, I think it means that there's some inheritance issue of the signal object) A working example for me is to create a new QThread/ QObject class with the Signal, and inject an instance to the log handler constructor. Somewhat like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52492689/7542501) example.

Comment: Just an FYI to future readers. If you get problems with the emit method, it is probably because of naming conflict between logging.Handler and QObject. See this answer for a solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66664679/4454875](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66664679/4454875)

Answer (score 15):

Here's a complete working example based on [mfitzp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28794076/3614835):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import logging

# Uncomment below for terminal log messages
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')    

class QPlainTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(parent)
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)    

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.widget.appendPlainText(msg)    


class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog, QPlainTextEditLogger):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)    

        logTextBox = QPlainTextEditLogger(self)
        # You can format what is printed to text box
        logTextBox.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(logTextBox)
        # You can control the logging level
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        self._button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self._button.setText('Test Me')    

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        # Add the new logging box widget to the layout
        layout.addWidget(logTextBox.widget)
        layout.addWidget(self._button)
        self.setLayout(layout)    

        # Connect signal to slot
        self._button.clicked.connect(self.test)    

    def test(self):
        logging.debug('damn, a bug')
        logging.info('something to remember')
        logging.warning('that\'s not right')
        logging.error('foobar')

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    app = None
    if (not QtGui.QApplication.instance()):
        app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    dlg = MyDialog()
    dlg.show()
    dlg.raise_()
    if (app):
        app.exec_()
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but what is the purpose of inheriting from `QPlainTextEditLogger` in `MyDialog`? I am trying to convert this example to PyQt5, and couldn't get it to work without removing that second inheritance. It seems to work fine without it.

Answer (score 5):

Alex's answer should be ok in a single thread scenario, but if you are logging in another thread (QThread) you may get the following warning:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
(Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

This is because you are modifying the GUI (`self.widget.appendPlainText(msg)`) from a thread other than the main thread without using the Qt Signal/Slot mechanism.

Here is my solution:

```py
# my_logger.py

import logging
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject

class Handler(QObject, logging.Handler):
    new_record = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        super(logging.Handler).__init__()
        formatter = Formatter('%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s|%(message)s|', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
        self.setFormatter(formatter)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.new_record.emit(msg) # <---- emit signal here

class Formatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatException(self, ei):
        result = super(Formatter, self).formatException(ei)
        return result

    def format(self, record):
        s = super(Formatter, self).format(record)
        if record.exc_text:
            s = s.replace('\n', '')
        return s
```

```py
   # gui.py

   ... # GUI code
   ...
   def setup_logger(self)
        handler = Handler(self)
        log_text_box = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(log_text_box)
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
        handler.new_record.connect(log_text_box.appendPlainText) # <---- connect QPlainTextEdit.appendPlainText slot
   ...
```

Comment: I just couldn't make this to work on PySide2 as you can't have several inheritance with QObject. To make it work I had to use old signals syntax like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349563/how-to-get-non-blocking-real-time-behavior-from-python-logging-module-output-t)

Comment: Very good answer! This should be the accepted one IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll want to use a [QPlainTextEdit](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qplaintextedit.html) widget set to read-only.

Consider changing the background color to gray to give the user a hint that it is not editable. It is also up to you if you want it to be scrollable or the text selectable.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14161360/3366053) can get you started subclassing QPlainTextEdit to scroll with output, save to a file, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Sifferman’s answer appears to be the most elegant to me. Regardless, I've tried all in this post. They all work, but notice that if you try, e.g., to write a test and create a log entry on it you might get a nasty error like

**RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPlainTextEdit has been deleted**

After loosing my mind for a couple hours, I noticed that it's quite important to delete the handler manually when closing the window,

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    ...
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    root_logger.removeHandler(self.logger)
    ... 
    super().closeEvent(event)
```