# PyQt4 to PyQt5: inheritance issue

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I wanted to convert [this code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35593078/882697) to PyQt5.
I am running into an issue that I don't understand:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import logging

class QPlainTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)


class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, QPlainTextEditLogger):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()    # <= Error here

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    app = None
    if (not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    dlg = MyDialog()
    dlg.show()
    dlg.raise_()
    if (app):
        app.exec_()
```

This produces the following error:

> ```
> super().__init__(parent)
> TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parent'
> ```

Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: The error message shows you exactly what is wrong and how to fix it, as does the original code snippet.

Comment: super().__init__()  to super().__init__(parent)   .. that error is crystal clear .. :)

Comment: @Achayan: That is what I've done :s. I'll try tonight.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Actually I pasted the wrong code I think... I have the parent argument in my call to __init__! I'll check tonight...