# How to set logging level (enable full debug info) in QtPy

Tags: python, qt, debugging, qtpy

It may seem like a trivial question, but I really can't find how to make my qtpy app display full debug info. I want to achieve an effect similar to what defining QT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT for C++ build in native Qt does.
So is short I want to debug Qt itself, as I sometimes encounter some SEGFAULTs.

Comment: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/How-to-debug-PyQt-PySide-internal-crashes-(segfaults)-affecting-Spyder and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655198/best-way-to-display-logs-in-pyqt/35593078

Comment: @Adiii I am trying to get to Qt internals, not to create my own logger, so the SO thread didn't help. But this link to spyder-ide mentions about gdb, which seems promising. I am now trying to make it work for me.