# QPlainTextEdit graphical bug on Windows & Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qplaintextedit

I'm writing a simple GUI that displays a live-updating log in a QPlainTextEdit.

This is the handler I am passing to `logging.Logger.addHandler()`

```py
class QPlainTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    """Modified From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655198/best-way-to-display-logs-in-pyqt"""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.widget.appendPlainText(msg)
        self.widget.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)

    def write(self, m):
        pass
```

It properly emits the log entries I'm looking for to the QPlainTextEdit element, however, there is a graphical glitch that persists regardless of platform (or compositing enabled/disabled).
Here's a video of the behaviour:

https://i.imgur.com/DTUbfcM.mp4

The lines are chopped in half unless I manually scroll the box or resize the splitter.

This also happens regardless of whether I implement auto-scrolling in the above snippet a la:

```
moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
```

What could be causing this?

Edit: I tried to reproduce this with the below example, but I'm not running into the same issue. I think this may be due to me creating the `QPlainTextEdit()` in my original code outside of the main window perhaps?

```py
import sys
import time

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

class Worker(QThread):
    newLine = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def run(self):
        for x in range(300):
            self.newLine.emit(f"Testing a very long line so that the words will wrap and hopefully reproduce the issue Testing a very long line so that the words will wrap and hopefully reproduce the issue {x}")
            time.sleep(0.1)


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.editor = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.editor.setReadOnly(True)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText("Go for it")

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.layout.addChildWidget(self.editor)
        self.layout.addChildWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_button_pressed)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.editor)
        self.show()

    def add_line(self, msg: str):
        self.editor.appendPlainText(msg)

    def start_button_pressed(self):
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.newLine.connect(self.add_line)
        self.worker.start()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Are you by any chance using logging within a separate thread?

Comment: @musicamante I am indeed logging from a different thread. I just tested the behavior while making a minimal repro example but could not actually reproduce. I am emitting a string to the QPlainTextBox from another thread, but I'm not running into the same issue

Comment: @James No direct access to GUI elements should *ever* happen from other threads. In the link you gave there *is* an [answer that is thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60528393/2001654). Use that.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you, that makes sense. I just came across that answer as well after you tipped me off to the threading issue. Cheers