How can I make a threadsafe logging handler subclass that triggers events in the main Qt loop?
I have a PySide6 application that uses threading and logging. My logger has a custom handler defined below, which pops up a messagebox that requires user attention for higher level logging events:
import logging
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
class QtHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        if record.levelno >= logging.ERROR:
            QMessageBox.critical(None, "Error", self.format(record))
        elif record.levelno >= logging.WARNING:
            QMessageBox.warning(None, "Warning", self.format(record))

This works fine for single-threaded operations, but fails when a thread needs to log something that would trigger the messagebox, since that occurs in the main loop and it is not safe to trigger main loop events from threads.
My first attempt to fix this was to try to make the popup box appear only through emission of a Signal mediated by Qt.QueuedConnection, like so:
import logging
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Signal, Slot, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

class QtHandler(logging.Handler, QObject):
    queue_messagebox = Signal(object)
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Initialize both QObject and logging.Handler
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        # Connect the signal to the slot using a queued connection to ensure thread safety
        self.queue_messagebox.connect(self.show_message_box, Qt.QueuedConnection)

    def emit(self, record):
        # This is where the logging record is processed
        self.queue_messagebox.emit(record)  # Emit the signal with the log record

    @Slot(object)
    def show_message_box(self, record):
        # Create the message box based on the log level
        if record.levelno >= logging.ERROR:
            QMessageBox.critical(None, "Error", self.format(record))
        elif record.levelno >= logging.WARNING:
            QMessageBox.warning(None, "Warning", self.format(record))

But this fails with the statement that my emit() function is getting too many arguments. My assumption is that this is due to the fact that both logging.Handler and QObject have methods called emit and I am overriding one of them, when I need both of them to work.
How can I address this conflict, or is there another way I could go about making this logging handler threadsafe?

I use something very similar to your QtHandler. With the inheritance switched (QObject first) it works for me on PyQt, but I also vaguely remember that it didn't work on PySide. You can always separate the logging handler and the signal emitter like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54644606/6439229

@mahkitah separating them is a good idea, I will explore that. Order of operations doesn't seem to help on PySide6 sadly.

@KBriggs It's strange that you get that error, as emit() is an heritage of the legacy signal/slot connection style, which is normally not used anymore, and since you're overriding without super call no related exception should be raised. Can you provide a complete MRE (including whatever may trigger emit()) and the full traceback you get? Note that you may try a tricky hack, which is to rename the emit of QObject (as class member) at the very first import and delete the original attribute. I'm not sure it would fix it, though, as PySide doesn't behave exactly as PyQt.

@musicamante see the posted answer, as we were able to get it working by separating QObject from logging.Handler

@KBriggs I did a small test and, as I was afraid, removing that attribute doesn't seem enough. It seems like PySide insists on using emit() anyway, and this seems one of the many issues that binding has (including the multiple inheritance oddities).

PySide has some weird quirks to be sure..

For posterity, this worked in the end, thank you @mahkitah for the suggested framework:
import logging
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Signal, Slot, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

#QObject designed solely to emit signals
class MessageBoxEmitter(QObject):
    emit_message = Signal(object)

class QtHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        # Create an instance of the internal QObject to handle signal emissions
        self.emitter = MessageBoxEmitter()
        # Connect the internal signal to the message box displaying slot - queued connection to ensure thread safety
        self.emitter.emit_message.connect(self.show_message_box, Qt.QueuedConnection)

    def emit(self, record):
        # Emit the signal with the log record
        self.emitter.emit_message.emit(record)

    @Slot(object)
    def show_message_box(self, record):
        # Create the message box based on the log level
        if record.levelno >= logging.ERROR:
            QMessageBox.critical(None, "Error", self.format(record))
        elif record.levelno >= logging.WARNING:
            QMessageBox.warning(None, "Warning", self.format(record))


Note that a similar question (and solution) already exists, and addressing the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66664542
